# Can I create Hadoop cluster with single VM?

Tags: hadoop

I am an experienced person in Java and wanted to get my hands dirty with Hadoop. I have gone through the basics and now preparing for the practical things.

I have started with the tutorials given at https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/ to setup and running hadoop on virtual machine.

So, to create a cluster I need multiple virtual machine running in parallel. right? And needs to add ip address of all in hadoop-site.xml. Or can I do it with single virtual machine?

Comment: Ideally yes, but for learning and developing in you local machine you can use [Hortonworks sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/sandbox/) which is a single cluster instance to hadoop for you to play with.

Comment: Thanks Sadi, I will give it a try. By saying "Single Cluster Instance" you mean single hadoop instance running in cluster, is it?

Comment: actually this is a mini hadoop ecosystem, since HDFS is one or two namenodes and a collection of datanodes, you'll actually get at least one name node and one data node with this. Try it out, also once you get comfortable and feel like running something taxing, you can try AWS or Azure cloud to get the feel of a true distributed computing. Have fun!

Comment: this is where I started, [word count](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot create a cluster with single VM. Cluster meaning is group of machines.

If you have a good configuration of Host machine, on top of that you can run 'n' number of guest OS. By doing like this only you can create Hadoop cluster (1 NN, 1 SNN, 1 DN)

If you want, you can install Pseudo mode (all services run in one machine) Hadoop, which runs like a testing machine

Comment: I do understand cluster is group of machines. My question is whether one can setup cluster without having group of machines (i.e. using VM).

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a multinode cluster using any virtual box like Oracle VM. Create 5 nodes(1-NN,1-SNN,3-DN). Assign each node its IP address and set up all the configuration files on all the nodes. There are 2 files - (Masters and slave). In the NN node give the IP address of SNN in Master file and all the 3 DN's IP address in the slave files. Also set up the ssh connectivity between all the nodes using the public keys.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can assign IP to each node? Or is it something auto assigned by hadoop?